# Breadcrumb navigation for all in one site

Tags: jquery

I have a set of links which represent different parts of a page that i show and hide.

Here is the list of links:

```
  <ul id="breadcrumbs">

      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>

      <li><a href="">1. Section1</a></li>

      <li><a href="">2. Section2</a></li>

      <li><a href="">3. Section3</a></li>

      <li><span></span></li>

    </ul>
```

They're purpose is to illustrate where the user is in the process.

I would like to be able to make these links clickable so that they can be used for navigation purposes.

However, the user should not be able to skip a step if they havent selected the relevant content in the previous step. And, ultimately, once they have gone through all the necessary steps i would like to make it so that they can go back and review their previous steps. At the moment, the page just defaults to the homepage when you press the back button because all of the content is on the same page.

I thought that maybe applying a class to my "visible" sections in my jquery script and then running an if/else statement checking for the class and handling the links would work, but that proved to be inefficient.

Could anyone shed a light on what would be the best way to go about this? Maybe a SWITCH statement would be in order here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your three sections are on a same page, and you use javascript to hide or show them.

I also suppose you have some method to validate the user selection like for exemple `validateStep(stepNumber)` which return `true` or `false`.

I suggest you to add the class "bread-section" to the `a` linked to sections
So you just have to call a method similar to the following every time you change step :

```
var updateBreadcrumb = function(){
  $('a.bread-section').each(function(i){
    $(this).toggleClass('enabled', validateStep(i))
  }
}
```

Then you can do the little modification to the click action on those links

```
var breadSectionClickAction = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $self = $(this);
  if(!$self.hasClass('enabled')) return;

  // do your show/hide section magic
  showSection($(a.bread-section).index($self)); // I supposed you have a method to show a specific section
}

$('a.bread-section').on('click', breadSectionClickAction);
```

And style the links accordingly:

```
.bread-section,
.bread-section:hover,
.bread-section:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}

.bread-section.enable {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #5555ee;
}

.bread-section.enable:hover,
.bread-section.enable:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I hope, I understood correctly what you wanted ;)